# html how to check multiple radio buttons

Tags: html, radio-button

I am creating simple website that have questions, each question have 4 radio buttons that only 1 can be selected, overall i have 10 questions.

The problem is that I can only select one from the 4*10 questions answers,

For each 4 radio buttons that presents the answer have the same name, and others have different names, what I done wrong??

Snippet from my code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-8">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        <div id="q0">
        </div>
        <label id="q0a1" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"></label>
        <label id="q0a2" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"></label>
        <label id="q0a3" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"></label>
        <label id="q0a4" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-8">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        <div id="q1">
        </div>
        <label id="q1a1" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio1"></label>
        <label id="q1a2" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio1"></label>
        <label id="q1a3" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio1"></label>
        <label id="q1a4" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio1"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you certain each set has a different name, and that there's no other code interfering with the radio buttons? because the code you posted [works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/hbryobc8/)

Comment: I updated your post with a snippet so you can see what you provided us. Are you sure that replicates your issue? Seems like it works fine to me.